# What are the settings needs to be done in Eclipse IDE to run C/C++ Clang format plugin?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clang, clang-format

I am new to the Eclipse. I want change the coding format of my eclipse c++ project to Clang format.
I checked in different forum and found Eclipse plugin "CppStyle 1.5.0.0". I have installed it and also updated the settings in Eclipse as mentioned below.
Reference : https://github.com/wangzw/CppStyle

**Properties -> C/C++ General -> Formatter -> Code Formatter -> CppStyle (Clang-format)**

After this i am selecting the code and pressing **Ctrl + Shift + f** to change the format.

But it give the Error code **"clang-format () does not exist."**

I checked many places but i did not found the solution yet. Is it something wrong with my eclipse setting or something else ?

System information:

Windows 10
Eclipse IDE Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Comment: Just for future reference,
I have update below settings to run clang-format in Eclipse.
--> In project Preferences, c/c++ -> CppStyle -> Clang-format path : ..\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe 
-->  Enable "Run clang-format on file save"
--> add ".clang-format" file to project root directory
After this whenever you change anything in code and press SAVE it will automatically change format according to your defined clang-format
if there are no ".clang-format" file found in project root directory it will update by default according to google clang format.

Comment: I also have same problem.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows it seems you have to install the entire LLVM set of binaries to get `clang-format.exe`. Get it from https://releases.llvm.org/download.html and install. If the default paths are used it will be found at `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe`. Go to **Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> CppStyle** and put this full path under **Clang-format path**.